# Groovy String array sort using float value truncating zeros at the end

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy

I have array of string float value, I want to sort it in the reverse order. any values ends with zero is truncating.

eg.

`25.200` comes with `25.2`

How to preserve the zero values?

Here is the code I have.

```
class Test {

    def static main(args){

        def tags = ["13.199", "14.200", "15.201", "25.220", "26.220", "3.200", "4.201", "5.201", "6.201", "7.202", "8.203", "9.205"]
        println tags.collect{it as Float}.sort{-it}
        println tags*.toFloat()?.sort()?.reverse()
        }
}
```

**output**

```
[26.22, 25.22, 15.201, 14.2, 13.199, 9.205, 8.203, 7.202, 6.201, 5.201, 4.201, 3.2]
[26.22, 25.22, 15.201, 14.2, 13.199, 9.205, 8.203, 7.202, 6.201, 5.201, 4.201, 3.2]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To keep the zeroes, you need to keep the strings.  But you need to sort by the float value (as you've seen)

One solution is to create a list for each element in your list. The first can be the float value, the second the original string

Then sort by the first element, and collect the second values

```
tags.collect { [ it.toFloat(), it ] }
    .sort { it[0] }
    *.getAt(1)​
```